# Get sibling categories in category.tpl for the current category in prestashop

Tags: categories, prestashop

I need to list **sibling categories** in the category page in a Prestashop theme. Currently  it **does** show the sub-categories if any but **not** the sibling categories.

A quick answer would really be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For to start i would have created a override file in /override/controllers/, named CategoryController.php

And add this:

```
<?php

class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
    public function displayContent()
    {
        // Get the global smarty object.
        global $smarty;

        // Get current category's parent.
        $parent_category = new Category($this->category->id_parent, self::$cookie->id_lang);

        // Get parent category's subcategories (which is current category's siblings, including it self).
        $category_siblings = $parent_category->getSubCategories((int)self::$cookie->id_lang)

        /* Assign your siblings array to smarty. */
        $smarty->assign(
            array(
                "category_siblings" => $category_siblings
            )
        );

        /* This we run the normal displayContent, but pass the siblings array to
           category.tpl */
        parent::displayContent();
    }
}

?>
```

I this the basic way to do it, i have not tested it get. You need to find a way to not list current category in the list of siblings.

If the code works you will now have an array in category.tpl named category_siblings, you now need to for example copy the code in category.tpl that outputs the subcategories and replace the subcategories arra with the category_siblings array.

Comment: Thanks a lot Niclas, I shall try and let you know, I have my fingers crossed! Just one thing, where to get a list of functions for Prestashop just like Wordpress codex?

Comment: Have not seen a codex for Prestashop. But you could probably build one with a documentation generator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators

Answer (score 2):

Thank you - works great!

You don't have to remove current category from array, intead just mark it as active. You have to edit category.tpl and in foreach subcategories loop insert:

```
<li {if $category->id == $subcategory.id_category}class="active"{/if}>
```

Its very nice navigation hack! Thanks one more time