# Prestashop subcategories menu inside a subcategory

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to show the subcategories menu of prestashop categories inside all subcategories. By default you only can see the subcategories menu inside a category but you cant see the "brother" subcategories of a subcategory.

I think I only need to make this code to work inside a subcategory because this code works well inside a category:

```
{foreach from=$subcategories item=subcategory}
<li >    <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($subcategory.id_category, $subcategory.link_rewrite)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"
class="cat_name">{$subcategory.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a>
</li>    {/foreach}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks so much

Comment: you'll need to be a little more specific.  what have you tried?  what didn't work?

Comment: I have tried to add this code: <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($subcategory.id_category, $subcategory.link_rewrite)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"
class="cat_name">{$subcategory.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a> in the subcategory page and didnt works, I think I need to edit the $ to others to works inside the subcategory page.

Answer (score 0):

as always i don't give you a full code, but i tell you how to do it.
in smarty you need to create a function that takes as param number of parent category,
and in this function you need to use Category::getChildren( $id_category );then in smarty you need only take a loop through the smarty function.

regards

and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

For to start i would have created a override file in /override/controllers/, named **CategoryController.php**

And add this:

```
<?php

class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
    public function displayContent()
    {
        // Get the global smarty object.
        global $smarty;

        // Get current category's parent.
        $parent_category = new Category($this->category->id_parent, self::$cookie->id_lang);

        // Get parent category's subcategories (which is current category's siblings, including it self).
        $category_siblings = $parent_category->getSubCategories((int)self::$cookie->id_lang)

        /* Assign your siblings array to smarty. */
        $smarty->assign(
            array(
                "category_siblings" => $category_siblings
            )
        );

        /* This we run the normal displayContent, but pass the siblings array to
           category.tpl */
        parent::displayContent();
    }
}

?>
```

And in **product-list.tpl** file:

```
<ul>
    {foreach from=$category_siblings item=elemento}
         <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($elemento.id_category, $elemento.link_rewrite)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="cat_name"> <li {if $category->id == $elemento.id_category}class="active"{/if}> {$elemento.name} </li> </a>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

via *[Get sibling categories in category.tpl for the current category in prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206886/get-sibling-categories-in-category-tpl-for-the-current-category-in-prestashop)*