# Displaying the subcategory of a subcategory in BigCommerce

Tags: handlebars.js, categories, bigcommerce

I have been through every possible trick that I can come up with in trying to make it possible, that I can display subcategories of a subcategory on my Bigcommerce supermarket theme.

Bigcommerce support and their community has been able to give me an idea on how to accomplish this, and to post here.

In list format, what I am trying to accomplish is this:

1. Parent Category

   - Subcategory

     - subcategory

Here is the page I am testing on:
https://www.flexibleassembly.com/programmable-tools-test/

I have currently set to this:

```
<!-- each parent-->
{{#each categories}}
<h2 class="sidebarBlock-heading" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</span></a></h2>
<div class="main-categories-group">
<div class="categories-container">

{{#each children}}
<!--begin include subcat-->
<div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
<div class="small-12 columns">
<div class="columns small-12"><a href="{{name}}"> <h3 class="button">{{name}}</h3> </a></div>
<div class="columns small-12"><a title="{{name}}" href="{{url}}" data-instantload> <img class="itemBorder lazyload" data-sizes="auto" src="{{cdn 'img/loading.svg'}}" data-src="{{getImage image 'category_card_size'}}" alt=" {{name}}" width=" 180px" height="180px" /> </a></div>
{{#if description.length}}
<hr />
<div class="seriesCardInfos columns small-12">
<div class="description" style="display: flex;">
{{{description}}}
</div>
</div>
<div class="columns small-12">
<div><a href="{{url}}"><button class="button button--primary">Shop Now!</button></a></div>
</div>
{{/if}}
</div>
</div>
<!--end include subcat-->
{{/each}}
</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
<!--end each parent-->
```

BigCommerce and our theme's developer, papathemes have suggested that we call it as "each category" and "children"

By doing this, while the code works - but it's pulling the first tier of categories; when I should be displaying the subcategories and their subcategories.

By changing from "categories" to "category.subcategories", I can display the subcategories, but the code will not pull their subcategories.

```
<!-- each parent-->
{{#each category.subcategories}}
<h2 class="sidebarBlock-heading" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</span></a></h2>
<div class="main-categories-group">
<div class="categories-container">

{{#each children}}
<!--begin include subcat-->
<div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
<div class="small-12 columns">
<div class="columns small-12"><a href="{{name}}"> <h3 class="button">{{name}}</h3> </a></div>
<div class="columns small-12"><a title="{{name}}" href="{{url}}" data-instantload> <img class="itemBorder lazyload" data-sizes="auto" src="{{cdn 'img/loading.svg'}}" data-src="{{getImage image 'category_card_size'}}" alt=" {{name}}" width=" 180px" height="180px" /> </a></div>
{{#if description.length}}
<hr />
<div class="seriesCardInfos columns small-12">
<div class="description" style="display: flex;">
{{{description}}}
</div>
</div>
<div class="columns small-12">
<div><a href="{{url}}"><button class="button button--primary">Shop Now!</button></a></div>
</div>
{{/if}}
</div>
</div>
<!--end include subcat-->
{{/each}}
</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
<!--end each parent-->
```

The first example confirms that my code indeed works, the problem is that there is no easy way to get the subcategories of a subcategory.

I looked at the following article to see if it can give me a direction to go. While it does have a method, I'm looking to see if there is an efficient way to do this now; it was from 7 years ago.
[Prestashop subcategories menu inside a subcategory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939260/prestashop-subcategories-menu-inside-a-subcategory)

Is it possible to do this with handlebars?

Answer (score 1):

Create a component file which will call itself until it gets to the end of the tree should do what you want if I understand correctly.

For example: components/list/category.html

```
 <li>
    {{name}}
    {{#if children}}
        <ul>
            {{#each children}}
                {{> components/list/category}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/if}}
</li>
```

Then in your page template:

```
<li>
  {{#each categories}}
    {{> components/list/category}}
  {{/each}}
</li>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and see what happens, thanks! This was the first idea that I had too as well, was what if I was to include an external file to call it.

We need to figure out this schema.json issue that we're having first in Stencil, before we can add additional files

Comment: For the component portion, I assumed that I would insert my code in that place. I didn't understand calling the path from within the page. How would I be able to define how to output the subcategory data?

While I inserted my code onto the component, and wrote the include on the layout. I still wasn't able to pull the subcategory of subcategories, only when setting "category.subcategories" to "categories" was I able to pull categories. 

Looks like I'm back at the spot I was once in.

Comment: I just updated my page to display the functionality between parent and child categories.

top portion: displays that I can show the subcategories on the parent page.

mid portion: shows that I am unable to show a subcategory's subcategories on the parent page

bottom portion: shows that I am able to execute the very same script, but it only works with the main primary categories.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, this definitely goes through all the categories and their children and outputs the name in a nested list. It will definately only work with a separate file that is called recursively. Can you get this simple example to work before you try and make more complex displays?

Comment: The code does indeed create a loop, however it only works at the base. I'm trying to reduce the three-click rule for efficiency. 

I switched the each from categories to category.subcategories

When you enter a category, it's subcategories are being listed, as well as their child categories.

I don't want to pull the entire website's list of categories, I want to be able to pull the "grandchild" categories of a parent category